# Can someone check my work on this probability problem?

Tags: probability, discrete-mathematics, permutations, solution-verification, combinations

A lady has 3 colours of nail polish to colour her fingernails. Each nail is
coloured in one colour.

If the lady picks colours at random, find the probability that there are at least 2 colours on each hand. Show a formula and compute a final answer.

my calculations:

the sample space |S| is all the different combinations of the 3 colors on all her fingers so |S| = P(10,3)

the probability that there are 2 colors on her hands is P(3,2)

and she needs at least 2 different colors on both her hands so i multiply the probabilities

P(3,2) * P(3,2) and then i divide with |S|

P(3,2)*P(3,2)/P(10,3)

Thanks in advance guys :)

Comment: Not following.  Assuming she chooses colors independently, there are $3^{5}$ ways for her to color the nails on one hand; these are all equiprobable.  Of these, there are only $3$ ways to do it with a single color.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your answer is not a perfect square, but the lady's hands are independent, so the answer should be a square.

There are $3^5=243$ ways to colour one hand's nails, and $3$ of them do not meet the requirement of having at least two colours (because they only use one colour). Therefore the probability that one hand will be coloured admissibly is $\frac{240}{243}$, and hence the final answer for both hands is $\frac{240^2}{3^{10}}$.

Comment: Thank you very much @Parcly